# How do I add an image directly below a text header?

Tags: html, css

[Here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/boyv75eu/1/)

I am trying to add the pencil directly below "blah" but it appears that margin-top isn't working....

In addition to that, I am having trouble understanding how to make the pencil directly below "blah" despite different screen sizes. I've been told that using percentages solves this issue, is that correct?

HTML:

```
  <head>
  <h1>Blah Pencil</h1>
  <img src = "http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Pencil-PNG-Pic.png" id = "pencil" height = "5%" width = "20%">
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pencil.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
  font-size: 590%;
}

body{
  background-image: url(https://www.xmple.com/wallpaper/graph-paper-grid-white-blue-1920x1080-c2-fdf5e6-1e90ff-l2-2-54-a-0-f-20.svg);
}

#pencil{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 21px;
}
```

Comment: So, the main issue is that header elements like an `h1` have build in margin that is pushing it down, but either way, this isn't the ideal approach if you want it to always be below the word "Blah". You should use absolute positioning based on an embedded span. I'll throw up a JSFiddle in a moment.

Comment: You may want to learn how to structure an html page, like what things belong within the head and body tags.

Comment: Is this kindof what you were looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/omy2w0k2/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one `span` in `h1` and put `img` inside it and use position `relative/absolute` on `span` and `img`

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
  font-size: 590%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://www.xmple.com/wallpaper/graph-paper-grid-white-blue-1920x1080-c2-fdf5e6-1e90ff-l2-2-54-a-0-f-20.svg);
}
span {
  position: relative;
}

h1 img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Blah<img src="http://www.stabilo-promotion.com/download/C27ad4c3cX13ba9b553a7X2665/STABILO_Giant_5430K_ALL_STABILO_red_SPP_150dpi.png" id="pencil"></span> Pencil</h1>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pencil.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```